# Why on earth won't my JS program run?

Tags: javascript

I posted a similar question earlier, but it was deleted because I felt I did a poor job in describing what my problem is.

Please see my current program here:

http://rich2233.comoj.com/

My jfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/rich2233/JGvAD/

I'm trying to emulate this game: http://javascript.internet.com/games/concentration.html

My version will not use images, it will instead use simple numbers.  It will alert the user how many tries it took them to match everything once the game has concluded.  It will also not keep track of time.

I think I have everything right with my code in terms of logic, however it doesn't run.  I'm new to JS and my debugging skills are limited, however I can't seem to find any syntax errors.  Could anyone help get this program working?  It would be greatly appreciated.

```
var attempts = 0;
var firstClick;             
var secondClick;
var numFoundPairs = 0;         
var click = true;

function display(id)
{
  attempts++;
  if (click == false)
  return;
  var num = parseInt(id);
  if (firstClick == null)
  {
  firstClick = num; 
  document.getElementById(id).value = a[num];
  return;
  }
  if (secondClick == null)
  secondClick = num;

 if (firstClick == secondClick)
 {  
 secondClick = null;
 return;
 }

 document.getElementById(boxNum).value = a[num];
 if (document.getElementById(firstClick).value != 
 document.getElementById(secondClick).value )
  {
  click = false;
  setTimeout ('hide(' + secondClick + ')', 3000);
  setTimeout ('hide(' + firstClick  + ')', 3000);
 }
 else
 {
 /* Show the identical blocks */
 firstClick = null;
 secondClick = null;
 }
 /* If the player found the eight pairs (since 16/2 = 8) */
 if (numFoundPairs == 8)
 {
  /* Let them know how many attempts it took them */
   alert ("You took " + Math.floor(String(attempts)/2) + " attempts.");  
  }
}
/* Function to hide the particular id */
function hide (id)
{
document.getElementById(id).value = "     ";
click = true;
}

/* Create the array of number and distribute them randomly on the grid */
function create()
{
a = new Array (1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 
             6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8);
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
{
var idx = Math.floor (Math.random() * a.length);
var tmp = a[i];
a[i] = a[idx];
a[idx] = tmp;
}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't run"? Anything in the console? How do you "run" it?

Comment: What errors do you get/problems do you run into?

Comment: Did you look in the error console to see what javascript errors there are?

Comment: All: I went ahead and uploaded my files to this website.  What I meant by "it doesn't run" is that when I click on the grid, a number appears but I can't do anything else.  Hopefully this makes things clearer: http://rich2233.comoj.com/

Comment: The variable `boxNum` is never defined.

Comment: Yeah, if I even tried to help you with this I would end up writing it for you. Some pointers, like @Inerdia said, `boxNum` is never defined, so it's throwing a js error on the second click. Your logic seems very wrong as well. You need to think about how events are firing and how your user would want to use this. For starters: http://jsfiddle.net/JGvAD/4/

Comment: The coding style does seem somewhat dated, circa 2001 maybe. Try to debug using Firebug. It's my best friend, really.

Comment: Thank you all. boxNum was a big error and I edited the .js script on the website.  Things seem a little buggy. I suppose my logic is terrible, I'm very new to all of this.

Comment: @Hunter Thanks very much! I'm going to observe the changes you made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error at http://rich2233.comoj.com/ occurs on line 28 of memory.js.

**Uncaught ReferenceError: boxNum is not defined**

You should look into using a JavaScript console like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) (for Firefox) or the Chrome developer tools (comes stock, CTRL+SHIFT+J to open them).  Firefox also has a JavaScript error window that comes stock as well.

They'll help you spot errors like this immediately.